# What is default behavior InsertEvent or InsertEventAsync

Tags: audit.net

For data providers that allow asynchronous operations, is the standard asynchronous method used?

If not, how do I deify this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean with deify the behavior, but most of the data providers implements both the sync and async methods, for example the `FileDataProvider`:

https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.NET/Providers/FileDataProvider.cs

However, the base class of the data providers calls the sync method from the virtual async methods, so if a custom data provider does not overrides the async methods, they will just call the sync method within a new task:

https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/8d410cb919f09d0c35f7c622d2e21913bcc46c59/src/Audit.NET/AuditDataProvider.cs#L58

```cs
public virtual async Task<object> InsertEventAsync(AuditEvent auditEvent)
{
    // Default implementation calls the sync operation
    return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => InsertEvent(auditEvent));
}
```

Which one is called depends on the context. If you call the `Save()` or `SaveAsync()` method on the `AuditScope`, it will call the sync or async version respectively. And the same happens for `Dispose()` / `DisposeAsync()` methods.

Consider the following example:

```cs
Audit.Core.Configuration.Setup()
    .UseSqlServer(sql => sql....)
    .WithCreationPolicy(EventCreationPolicy.InsertOnEnd);

using (var scope = AuditScope.Create("test", () => target, null))
{
    target.Status = "Updated";
} // <---- Dispose() will call InsertEvent()

await using (var scope = await AuditScope.CreateAsync("test", () => target, null))
{
    target.Status = "Updated";
} // <---- DisposeAsync() will call InsertEventAsync()
```